# Logging time towards commercial pilots license

Tags: faa-regulations, cpl

I am in a part 141 program trying to finish up my commercial pilots license. The airport we operate out of will be closed for a few weeks so I was wondering if I'd be able to rent a plane close to where I'm from to knock out some of the solo hours I have left. It wouldn't be a school plane and my instructor wouldn't be with me. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have a PPL?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If you are asking whether solo time logged outside the 141 program can count toward completion of the 141 program, I believe the answer is no. If you are asking whether you could finish your license requirements and earn your license under §61, the answer is yes.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information but you answered my question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are already a private pilot working on your commercial ticket. There is no requirement to do your solo hours at one flight school. Just make sure your primary instructor knows what you are doing and is OK with it.